# npm dependencies error in @types/styled-components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, styled-components

I have recently added revo calender plugin to my react project in which `@types/styled-components` dependency from npm is required, After installing it locally and pushing it to github when my peers download the project through git clone they aren't able to install the dependency automatically through `npm install`, it requires an additional command to install the dependency. this is also a problem when I try to host my project. what's the issue and why can't I use npm install to automatically install all the dependencies?

The error:

[image: The Error]

Package.json:

[image: Package.json]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't add images of error and code. Paste them in the question instead. Have a nice day.

Comment: Don't you just need to also do an `npm i styled-componenets` ?

Comment: Yeah! I Missed that, But is there any way we can automatically install those with just `npm install` if i already have it in my package.json?

Comment: @STRIZER_ORTIX yes you can do `npm install` to automatically install those but _only if you have them_ in your package.json. `@types/styled-components` and `styled-components` are two completely unrelated module.

Comment: that's the issue....both the dependencies are in my package.json but I'm not able to install it automatically @yqlim